# Deploying a Java web service with Apache Axis to IIS

Tags: iis, axis

I am working on a project to deploy a Java web service using Axis that will ultimately be hosted by an IIS web server.  We have generated the stub Java classes using the WSDL2Java Axis utility.  Our next step is to deploy the SOAP web service to IIS.  Does anyone have any advice on the best way to approach that?  It seems that Axis is meant to be used more with Tomcat versus IIS.  Can you deploy Axis generated SOAP web services to be hosted by IIS?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am looking at implementing pretty much the same thing, and i would like not having to use Tomcat.